# How to find if a string has a character which isn't in another string

Tags: python, string, character, bioinformatics, negation

For example I can have the string 'acagtcas' and I want to find if the string has any characters that **aren't** a, c, g or t. I've tried using not but I haven't been able to make it work. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):

```py
s = "acagtcas"

x = set(s).difference("acgt")
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
{'s'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comprehension to check the validity of each letter, and then use `any()` to see whether at least one of them is invalid:

```py
valid_letters = 'acgt'
data = 'acagtcas'

any(letter not in valid_letters for letter in data)
```

Output:

```py
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
valid_letters = 'acgt'
data = 'acagtcas'

print(bool(set(data)-set(valid_letters)))
```

output:

```py
True
```

```py
valid_letters = 'acgt'
data = 'acagtcas'

print(set(data)-set(valid_letters))
```

Output:

```py
{'s'}
```